# Get all the information on the website through LinkedIn API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I'm working on an app for LinkedIn. I want to access all the information available on the website but the API doesn't return most of them. I was wondering how to get them.

I can use screen scraping but I wonder why the API doesn't return the information when I can easily access it on the website?

For instance [this profile](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/pedro-dos-santos/1/811/b46) has many education information and it's public but none is returned via the API!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LinkedIn API is purposely designed to return certain datasets, some that are only accessible via the website and not the API.

Also, scraping any part of LinkedIn's website or its content is in violation of the LinkedIn API Terms of Use: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use